# DHTMLX Multiselect Drop-down Checkbox filter for Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

I'm trying to filter my Gantt Chart using a drop-down checkbox list. this is my code

index.html

```
<label class="text-primary" for="department">Select by Departments: </label>
    <select id="department" style="width:200px; height:20px; " mode="checkbox">
                            <option value="ALL" selected="1" >ALL</option>
                            <option value="ARTIST">ARTIST</option>
                            <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
                            <option value="LEAD">LEAD</option>
                            <option value="HR">HR</option>
                            <option value="PRODUCTION">PRODUCTION</option>
                            <option value="MANAGEMENT">MANAGEMENT</option>
                            <option value="TECHNOLOGY">TECHNOLOGY</option>
                        </select>
```

function

```
<script>
            var myCombo;
            function checkbox_department() {
            myCombo = dhtmlXComboFromSelect("department");
            myCombo.attachEvent("onCheck", function(value, state){
                gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskDisplay", function (id, task) {
                    var department_value = value

                     if (task.job_category == department_value || department_value == 'ALL') {
                     console.log(value);
                         return true;
                    }
                 });
                 gantt.render();
            });

            }

        </script>
```

the job_category came from a JSON file.

so far I manage to filter the gantt chart with any first checkbox I checked but when I check another checkbox, let say i check artist and production  everything disappear and in the console log it'll display

```
3PRODUCTION
7ARTIST
2PRODUCTION
52ARTIST
PRODUCTION
51ARTIST
2PRODUCTION
3ARTIST
PRODUCTION
22ARTIST
```

It will turn out like that, it would be easier if i just print screen the whole thing here but I'm using my office desktop and file uploading is blocked. Can anyone help me solves this issue, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your combo adds an onBeforeTaskDisplay handler each time user checks combo value, while never removing previously added handlers when an option becomes unchecked/unselected.
I'd suggest to store combobox selection in some scope variable and declare only one onBeforeTaskDisplay handler which will filter gantt by the value of that variable.

Then, inside onCheck handler of combo you update a scope variable with the selection state of the combo and call gantt repaint in order to invoke filtering

Your code may look following:

```
var myCombo;
function checkbox_department() {
    var department_value = 'ALL';

    myCombo = dhtmlXComboFromSelect("department");
    myCombo.attachEvent("onCheck", function(value, state){
        department_value = value;// put combo value into scope variable
        gantt.render();// and repaint gantt
    });

    // filter gantt by value of the scope variable
    gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskDisplay", function (id, task) {
        if (task.job_category == department_value || department_value == 'ALL') {
            console.log(value);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

and here is a simplified demo in case i got something wrong with the explanation and code sample
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/snippet/b6053d50

**Update:**

If you have a multiselect combo, you may need a bit different code. Something following should work:

```
var myCombo;
function checkbox_department() {
    var department_value = {'ALL': true};

    myCombo = dhtmlXComboFromSelect("department");
    myCombo.attachEvent("onCheck", function(value, state){
        var values = myCombo.getChecked();
        department_value = {};// put combo value into scope variable
        for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            department_value[values[i]] = true;// build hash for easy check later
        }
        gantt.render();// and repaint gantt
    });

    // filter gantt by value of the scope variable
    gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeTaskDisplay", function (id, task) {
        if(department_value['ALL'])
            return true;

        return !!department_value[task.job_category];
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks a bunch for your answer, you're a life saver. It works, but there are one more combo box i need to code it its similar but tad bit different approach than this, I may require your assistance again in near future, will keep you post, once again thanks. Would have upvote your answer but unfortunately I have less than 15 reputation currently

Comment: Hello again @alex-klimenkov, I have another issue that i require you help

1) how do I change the position(padding/margin) of the combo box? i tried  using css and it didnt work

Comment: 2) Now I'm trying to call the <select> option form a json file but it gave me an empty "undefined" box instead .
this is my code

 `<script>
  var myCombo;
  function doOnLoad() {
   myCombo = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone", "combo", 230, "checkbox");
   myCombo.load("common/data.json");
   myCombo.enableFilteringMode(true);
  }
 </script>`

jason file

`{"department":[
    {value: "1", "position":"Artist"},
    {value: "2", "position":"Lead"},
    {value: "3", "position":"Technology"}
]}`

Comment: hi!
1)Do you mean the positioning of dhtmlx combo? You can apply margin using selector:
http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/e0eec8f96 (check the html tab for html/css) 
Padding applied that way won't work too well since elements inside combo are absolute positioned. The easier solution would be to wrap combo into some div and position that outer div instead - http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5cc26e64f

Comment: 2) combo expects json to be a bit different:
- { "options" : [ {"value":"id", "text":"label"}, ...] }
here is a sample of working file https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/15721/63476/o11WUaUME0ZZ0PH/dhx_combo_json.zip

Comment: Hi again Alex, apologies for the late reply, I manage to solve both of the problem thanks to year guidance. There is still some issue for the checkbox filter when I want to filter from 2 different checkbox, I start giving me logic error, but I'll save that for another day. thanks again for all your help